# Debugging minification process with uglify-broccoli-js

Tags: javascript, minify, bundling-and-minification, broccolijs

My web application doesn't get compressed nor mangled by uglify-broccoli-js.

For some reason the .min.js files are not created. Is there any way to have an error log, a verbose mode, to see what's going wrong during the minification process?